# How to allow user to type in certain number of input value before decimal and certain number of input value after decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The type of input should only be numbers and backspace, del should be allowed. 
Example - 3 numbers before decimal and 2 numbers after decimal
should allow us only following type of inputs -

- 333
- 221.22
- 1
- 12
- 9999(not allowed)
- 999.999(not allowed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```js
const input = document.querySelector(".enforce-pattern");

input.oninput = input.onchange = function(){
  input.value = input.value.match(/^\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{0,2})?/);
};
```

```html
<input class="enforce-pattern" type="text">
```